# How do stored procedures get explicitly executed upon end user input

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a java file that creates a username by accepting user inputs and then stores that username in a Microsoft SQL Server database. My SQL guy has written a number of stored procedures that do most of the heavy lifting, including a stored procedure that accepts and stores the username in the database. I am having some difficulty figuring out where I place what code though, especially when I try to logically think my way through what I'm doing. My example code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CreateUsername {
    public JFrame f = new JFrame("Account Login");
    public JButton Submit = new JButton("Submit");
    public JTextField user = new JTextField(30);

    public CreateUsername() {

        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.add(Submit);
        f.add(user);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        Submit.setBounds(50, 100, 195, 30);
        user.setBounds(50, 130, 195, 30);
        Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //closes the create username window when clicking submit

                f.dispose();

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                Class.forName(com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver());
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(""); // insert database connection info between quotes
                 
                String sql_string = "CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser] (\n" +
                        "\t@UserName varchar(30),\n" +
                        "\t@UserID int OUTPUT)\n" +
                        "AS\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "DECLARE\t  @return_value int\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]\n" +
                        "           ([UserName])\n" +
                        "     VALUES\n" +
                        "           (@UserName)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "SELECT\t@UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()\n" +
                        "go";

                CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(sql_string);

                cs.execute();
```

Obviously the code is incomplete, but a few issues become clear as you look over the code. My primary concern here is the formatting of the lines of code that deal with connecting to the database (I've seen a few examples of how to do it and they all vary slightly so I'm confused). Also, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to "attach" the callable statement (stored procedure) to the appropriate location (aka after the submit button is pressed, stored procedure executes). I have a user interface, and I have a stored procedure that I want to execute after the user has entered their username and clicked submit, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I feel I have exhausted google searches on the subject (which tells me there is probably something more fundamentally wrong with my understanding of something). Any help would be much appreciated. Again this code will not compile as is, I am aware of this, I just need help with how to continue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The stored procedure needs to be *created* in your database (separate from your app), then you *call* the stored procedure with parameters and get back a result. `GO` is not a command anyway, it's a batch separator used in SSMS and sqlcmd

Comment: Yes, all these are stored procedures created in the database, retrieved from the database through intellij connection to said database. I was having issues arranging the proper syntax to call the stored procedure, my code is arranged the way it is because that's the best I could figure out from multiple examples/tutorials and hours of googling. I understand I need to call the stored procedure with parameters but my issue is I like to understand, practically speaking, what all the code is doing (I understand some but not all, for example:

Class.forName(com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver());

Comment: I have also seen people use DriverManager.registerDriver(com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver()); and I really don't understand what either of these do, if they are needed, and which one is needed in my case. Googling it doesn't seem to help since the explanation isn't very beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the only purpose of your program is to insert a username into a database, I would probably ditch the whole AWT stuff and just use a fully console based application approach for this since everything else is (in my opinion) a bit overkill. Using a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and `System.out.print` / `System.out.println` - it's not only easier to develop, it's also a lot more straight forward than GUI programming in general.

The main method is the entry point of your program. The code to insert something into the database does not belong there, when using an AWT based approach. The main class should actually create an instance of your GUI and everything else is taken care of by methods in a class you'd create. I personally develop mainly backend Java or JSF frontends, thus I am not too familiar with AWT or Java GUI programming in general, but I have plenty of experience with C# in that regard.

A very simple approach would be something like:

1. Show GUI
2. When submit button is clicked (see: [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)) , validate the input, if valid, create a new instance of your database connection, ditch the stored procedure and use plain SQL with [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) + parameter binding (to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) - especially for beginners, I think it's important to learn basic SQL and how to use it properly!

In some extremely simplified and not pretty much abstracted pseudocode:

```
main(args)
{
GUI gui = new GUI();
gui.show();
}

actionPerformed(Event)
{
Database db = estabilishDatabaseConnection();
Statement stmt = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO USERS (name) VALUES (:name)");
stmt.bindParameter("name",userInput.getValue();
stmt.execute();
}
```

Whereas a console based approach would look like:

```
main(args)
{
print("Username: ")
username = readInput();
// from here: basically the same as the actionPerformed in the first example
}
```

However, I think the best approach would be to divide your problem into smaller sub-problems and solved these individually: e.g. `("how to connect to a database", "how to create a prepared statement", "how to bind a parameter to a prepared statement", "how to execute a method when button is clicked", "what is a class", "what is a constructor", "why do I have to close connections", "how to retrieve a value from a text input", "how to use try with resources", ...)`

Good luck on your journey!

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful and detailed response. I've gone over your response with my sql expert (and head of the application development) and he says we need to use GUI, so a console approach won't work in this case. However, the rest of your answer is extremely useful in explaining where parts of my code need to go. I know the basic structure of a java file, and honestly it feels silly to me now to think that I thought the stored procedure would go in the main method. I will try some of your suggested sub problem searches, as a few of them look to be particularly useful for me. Thanks!